# Update Actionsheet title with state value

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

1) I have a Flatlist, Inside the renderItem method I have Actionsheet & the code is below:

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => (
<TouchableOpacity onLongPress={() => {this.longPressed(item)}} activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={() => this.actionOnRow(item)} underlayColor="white">
        <ListItemViewCell data={item} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
<ActionSheet
        ref={o => this.ActionSheet = o}
        title={this.getTitle()}
        options={['Generate', 'Delete', 'Cancel']}
        cancelButtonIndex={2}
        destructiveButtonIndex={2}
        onPress={(index) => {
            if (index == 0) {
              this.generate(this.state.selectedListing)
            }
            if (index == 1) {
              this.delete(this.state.selectedListing)
            }
          }}
      />
)
getTitle() {
    return this.state.selectedProfileName
  }
```

"getTitle" method return's the profile name from the selected Cell in Flatlist.
But for me here In Actionsheet the title is not being displayed.
I have also binded the "getTitle" method in constructor.

The "getTitle()" method is getting called till the number of flatlist items.
Can someone please suggest me How to go further for displaying the title in ActionSheet?
**UPDATED:**

3) Can I have access of item inside "

**UPDATED:**
In Render method

```
  <FlatList
  data={this.state.data}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={this.flatListItemSeparator}
  ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
  // onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
  refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
  onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
  onEndReachedThreshold={0}
  onRefresh={this.refreshProfiles}
/>
```

After the list is generated from flatlist, When I longpress the flatlist item I want to show two options on Actionsheet for which i have used "[https://github.com/beefe/react-native-actionsheet][1]".

In Cell longpress method I am updating the state value & I am trying to trigger the Actionsheet as like below

```
longPressed(item) {
    console.log("Long pressed " + JSON.stringify(item)
    this.setState({
      selectedProfileName: item.name
    },() => {
      console.log("selected Listing "+ this.state.selectedProfileName)
      this.ActionSheet.show()
    })
  }
```

In setstate completion I am calling the actionsheet's show() method. After updating the state value also, the profile name is not been showed in Actionsheet title.

Can someone plz help me to fix this  [1]: https://github.com/beefe/react-native-actionsheet

The JSON response for item is

```
{ "id": 985646, "name": "Business Name", "website": "businesswebsite.com", "formatted_website": "businesswebsite.com", "is_favorite": false }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not binding. If you have binding, your code should look like this.

```js
title={this.getTitle.bind(this)}

OR

title={() => this.getTitle()}
```

And If you're using the status values, you don't have to call a function.

```js
title={this.state.selectedProfileName}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response, I have tried using state value but, the state value is not being updated. & when I updated with the bind as you said, the "getTitle" method is not getting called, I checked by keeping a log statement

Comment: @iOSDev Show how your ActionSheet is structured through the Edit Question.

Comment: i couldn't get what you have said

Comment: I have updated the structure, could you please check

Comment: @iOSDev You are updating 'selectedName'. But what you use is 'selectedProfileName'. The value are different from each other.

Comment: "selectedName" this was mistake only, while writing code here in the stack.
But in actual code I have its "selectedProfileName".

Comment: What happens if you put in the actual value?

Comment: @hongdeveloper hi, i am trying the same as the above but in my onPress i am trying to navigate to a new screen but it is not working, i keep getting `undefined is not an object(evaluating 'navigation.navigate')`

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this below code
Step 1: Check the item data by using alert

```js
renderItem = (item) => (
alert(JSON.stringify(item))
<TouchableOpacity onLongPress={() => {this.longPressed(item)}} activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={() => this.actionOnRow(item)} underlayColor="white">
        <ListItemViewCell data={item} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
<ActionSheet
        ref={o => this.ActionSheet = o}
        title={this.getTitle()}
        options={['Generate', 'Delete', 'Cancel']}
        cancelButtonIndex={2}
        destructiveButtonIndex={2}
        onPress={(index) => {
            if (index == 0) {
              this.generate(this.state.selectedListing)
            }
            if (index == 1) {
              this.delete(this.state.selectedListing)
            }
          }}
      />
)
getTitle() {
    return this.state.selectedProfileName
  }
```

**